# ClickOnce single file publishing missing .dll.config.deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2022, clickonce

I published a WPF app with ClickOnce with Single File option. But when I run the .application file, it shows error message that a file is missing so it can't run the program. There is a Details link in the popup. When I click on it, it shows a text file with error details:

```
Downloading file:///C:/Users/...Project Name..dll.config.deploy did not succeed.
```

Anyone encountered same issue?